# CakePHP AuthComponent that uses Cookies instead of Sessions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want the AuthComponent to use encrypted client-side cookies for easier scalability.

So what I did was copy `/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php` to `app/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php` (I'm using CakePHP2), added `Cookie` to the
`$components` array, and replaced all instances of `CakeSession` with `$this->Cookie` (manually after proof-reading) making sure it was essentially just dumping things in the same format as default except on Cookies.

Here is the error I get: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ...`

Why is it not picking up $this as a Controller? I should be able to use one Component in another seamlessly. Is there any quick-hack to this using ClassRegistry or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the AuthComponent to use encrypted client-side cookies for easier scalability.

What is this supposed to mean? How exactly do cookies scale better than sessions?

What you're doing sounds like a bad idea. Cookies can only be so big, and you might now be storing sensitive information in plaintext on clients' computers. How are you 'encrypting' your cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it works for now, I just removed the 'static' keyword from the *read()* and *password()* functions.